# jQuery file upload to S3 (and rails) with CORS headers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

Im trying to upload a file directly to S3, and displaying a progress bar while it uploads.
But when I submit the form, I get the following error message:

> OPTIONS https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket 403 (Forbidden)
>   9:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403. 9:223 fail

This is my form:

```
%form#file_upload(action=@aws_s3_url method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data")
  -# order is important!
  -# also, the things that are not filled in right now *will* be filled in soon.  See below.
  %input{:type => :hidden, :name => :key}
  %input{:type => :hidden, :name => "AWSAccessKeyId", :value => "ACCESS_KEY"}
  %input{:type => :hidden, :name => :acl,  :value => :private}
  %input{:type => :hidden, :name => :success_action_redirect}
  %input{:type => :hidden, :name => :policy}
  %input{:type => :hidden, :name => :signature}

  .fileupload-content
    .fileupload-progress
  .file-upload
    %label.fileinput-button
      %span Upload Document
      %input{:type => :file, :name => :file}
```

And this is my javascript code, using the `jquery-file-upload` plugin:

```
$(function() {
  $('#file_upload').fileupload({
    //forceIframeTransport: true,    // VERY IMPORTANT.  you will get 405 Method Not Allowed if you don't add this.
    autoUpload: true,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    add: function (event, data) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/projects/9/create_file",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {doc: {title: data.files[0].name}},
        async: false,
        success: function(retdata) {
          // after we created our document in rails, it is going to send back JSON of they key,
          // policy, and signature.  We will put these into our form before it gets submitted to amazon.
          $('#file_upload').find('input[name=key]').val(retdata.key);
          $('#file_upload').find('input[name=policy]').val(retdata.policy);
          $('#file_upload').find('input[name=signature]').val(retdata.signature);
          $('#file_upload').find('input[name=success_action_redirect]').val(retdata.success_action_redirect);
        }

      });

      console.log(data)
      file = data.files[0]
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
      $('#file_upload').append(data.context)

      data.submit();
    },
    progress: function (event, data) {
      progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
      console.log("Progress")
      data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
    },
    send: function(e, data) {
      // show a loading spinner because now the form will be submitted to amazon,
      // and the file will be directly uploaded there, via an iframe in the background.
      //$('#loading').show();
      console.log("Loading")
    },
    fail: function(e, data) {
      console.log('fail');
      console.log(data);
    },
    done: function (event, data) {
      // here you can perform an ajax call to get your documents to display on the screen.
      $('#your_documents').load("/documents?for_item=1234");

      // hide the loading spinner that we turned on earlier.
      $('#loading').hide();
    },
  });
});
```

I know the code works because when I uncoment forceIframeTransport it processes the request. The problem is that using that method you only get a progress event once (when is completed), so it defeats the purpose of having a progress bar. I read that to do without the forceIframeTransport, you have to set the CORS headers, which I do in rails like this:

```
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

#, DELETE, OPTIONS
#DELETE, OPTIONS

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://0.0.0.0:3000/*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '3000'
end

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://0.0.0.0:3000/*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Token'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '3000'

    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
```

And they are indeed sent, because when I manually do the GET "/projects/9/create_file" (With the advance rest plugin for example) i get the following response headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://0.0.0.0:3000/*
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept,
>
> Authorization, Token Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000

Also, this is my CORS configuration in amazon:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://0.0.0.0:3000/*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Any ideas about what could be wrong?

Comment: Notice that the error message says `localhost` and you are allowing `0.0.0.0:3000`. The browser may redirect `0.0.0.0` to `localhost` but they are not the same.

Comment: You can use something like http://xip.io/ to get an external url.

Comment: No, I have tried changing both the CORS allowed origin config in amazon to https://127.0.0.1:3000/*, and the one my rails app sets (its running in that address), and it still gives the same message

Comment: `127.0.0.1:3000 != localhost` its the same issue. Try using XIP.io, a staging app on a remote server or a virtual host.

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it. Enter `127.0.0.1:3000` in the browser and then type `document.domain` ("127.0.0.1") in the console. Then go to `localhost:3000` and do the same.

Comment: I have tried setting everything to http://my-ip.xip.io:3000/* but it still gives the same error message. Funny enough, if i try it in firefox instead of chrome it gives a different error message: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but your 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' definition is a little strange. If you want to allow any path on `example.com` you would do `<AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>` without the wildcard on the end. Also have you wrapped your `<CORSRule>` in a `<CORSConfiguration>` element as on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html. The actual syntax for the field is http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#section-7.1

Comment: yeah, that was it!!! Its apparently not allowed to add a * after the url. Also, I had to remove the redirect_on_success as apparently its not allowed under aws cors access. If you want answer the question and Ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow any subpath on `https://example.com` you would do:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
</CORSRule>
```

The [origin header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1) can either be a wildcard (*) or a url containing one or no wildcard. Ex:

```
https://*.example.com
```

However adding the wildcard on the end `https://0.0.0.0:3000/*` will not allow any path as one could guess.

Comment: Link is broken, is it possible to allow this in a coffeescript file?

Comment: @fatfrog Link is not broken - it's the EITF... And setting the CORS headers in a coffee script file does not make any sense as it's a header sent from the server.

Comment: Thanks, look like it was a temporary outage.  I installed a CORS plugin, on chrome, and the error changed to 413 (Request Entity Too Large) - can this be resolved if you are running on localhost?

Comment: Why are you asking this as a comment on answer instead of creating a question?